# Which application receives which hotkey? (List X clients which hold key grabs.)

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xkb

How can I list the X clients which registered for a specific keyboard event (i.e. a key press; a shortcut thing). Those things are called passive key(board) grabs.

And the list should contain what that application is registered for what keysyms (with what modifiers).

Comment: A better duplicate for this question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261371/how-do-i-find-out-what-program-owns-a-hotkey

Answer (score 1):

See [this previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166363/find-out-which-application-listens-to-specific-key-bindings) and [this one.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/manipulating-x-key-and-pointer-grabs-on-the-command-line)

The first answer to the second question above discusses a way of asking X to write a list of current key grabs to the X log:

```
xdotool key XF86LogGrabInfo
```

although when I tried it, it didn't display some of the grabs I expected to see.

`xev` is also a useful tool for diagnosing X event problems. It brings up a window, and logs all keyboard and mouse events sent to that window. If you press a key and the `window` field of the corresponding log message is `0x0`, they key event was probably captured by the window manager.

Comment: The X server has perfect knowledge about which application  has which (passive) keyboard grabs. And it doesn’t _modify_ keysyms, it is instead responsible to have a mapping for key events to keysyms. `xmodmap` is outdated since 1996. Grabbed keys are not passed to the window in focus. And last but not least: the window manager does not participate in event distribution in any special way.

Comment: Apparently I was working under some misconceptions. I've removed them from my answer, and added information from another question, linked.