# Can't reassign shortcut Super+O under Gnome

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-shell

- Kernel: Linux 4.15.7-1-ARCH
- GNOME: 3.26.2

I am unable to assign a program to Super+O. When I try setting it in Gnome settings, it doesn't even get registered as a shortcut (i.e. I open the "Pick shortcut" window, press Super+O and nothing happens).

I used dconf-editor to set the shortcut, but Gnome still refuses to acknowledge it.

Other programs pick up Super+O just fine. However, after setting the shortcut (which works in e.g. Guake settings), the shortcut itself doesn't work.

Comment: Works fine here (same distro, same desktop).Most likely that key combo is [already grabbed by another application](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261371/22142).

Comment: @don_crissti if I send the shortcut with xdotool, it gets assigned just fine :/ Nothing shows up in logs, either.

Comment: Odd... As I said, it works fine here, so not sure what to advise...

Comment: Probably some other app that you have installed is somehow hijacking it.

Comment: Same problem here (Ubuntu 18.04, GNOME 3.28).  Looks like it might be used for screen rotation lock, but there's no info about to change it...

Comment: I poked around with some settings related to GNOME Shell extensions (specifically dash to panel) and suddenly it works... but I now I can't reproduce the problem.  Weird.  Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069580/ubuntu-18-04-supero-cant-trigger-shortcut-event