# xbindkeys claims there is a conflict with another program, which makes it unable to grab all the defined keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, input, xbindkeys

I installed `xbindkeys` to catch my custom key shortcuts, and `xte` in order to emulate the key presses i want to execute. This **does** work, but with a lot of issues.

I have to press my key combination very many times in order to get it to work once in a while, the success rate on that being about 15% or so. So as recommended by [the archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys#Troubleshooting), i ran `xbindkeys -n` to see if any errors are encountered, which gave me the following output:

> *** Warning ***
> Please verify that there is not another program running
> which captures one of the keys captured by xbindkeys.
> It seems that there is a conflict, and xbindkeys can't
> grab all the keys defined in its configuration file.

To my knowledge, i haven't installed any software that should conflict with catching pressed keys (at least not on purpose). I am running Xubuntu 20.40, and i don't know if any such software comes with it...

If it makes any difference, the keys are all defined with the Super modifier. I did remove all the default shortcuts from XFCE that implement the Super key, from the Keyboard > Application shortcuts, and from the Window Manager > Keyboard entries.

How would i check to see what is causing the conflict, and then go about resolving it?

Comment: Could you check if you are running X11 or Wayland? Wayland is well-known for it's f****** architecture when it comes to keybinding. You can check session type with `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE `.

Comment: Sure thing, it outputs `x11`

Comment: Can you find who the culprit is? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261371/how-do-i-find-out-what-program-owns-a-hotkey/261383#261383 (Arguably your question is a duplicate of that one)

Comment: It might be, thanks for linking that. My log file doesn't seem nearly as neat as his example there, and i cannot figure out how to find the info i need in it... but it seems like the right place to look.