# Alt + 4 tab switch doesn't work in Manjaro Linux KDE Plasma

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro Linux, with KDE Plasma as desktop environment, ran by a Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB.

In applications that have tabs, I can navigate through the tabs using `alt + tab number`. All combinations work, except for `alt + 4` (I'm using the numbers that are located at the top of the letters, not the numpad).

So, for example, when I'm on Firefox or Visual Studio Code, and I have 5 tabs open, I can quickly change to any specific tab, except for the 4th one. The `alt + 1` combination works, the `alt + 5` combination works, but when I press `alt + 4` nothing happens, so the 4th tab must be accessed in other ways (oh the horror!).

Is that specific key combination being used by the operating system? How can I change this behavior, so that `alt + 4` correctly switches to the 4th tab of the current focused application?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've got a global shortcut assigned to Alt + 4.

Please check https://docs-staging.kde.org/trunk5/en/khotkeys/kcontrol/khotkeys/shortcuts.html

Comment: Maybe this application itself has shortcuts? Can you check that please?

Comment: Please try this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261371/how-do-i-find-out-what-program-owns-a-hotkey If you find out what it is, please share it with us. Perhaps this issue affects others as well.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are using a Spanish keyboard? If so, there is a default shortcut set to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>, which is <kbd>4</kbd> in those keyboards, as Sahsanu says [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/ckzdvp/comment/evsvz87/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Solution:

> ...go to System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Kwin and in option "Walk Through Windows of Current Application (Reverse)" remove or change the assigned keys "Alt+~"