# something grabs the keyboard when I press the audio previous key on my keyboard

Tags: x11, xfce, input

When I press the audo play and audio next keys on my keyboard the keypress goes through to my application, but when I press the audio previous key something is grabbing the keypress and preventing it from going through to my application.  How can I find out what is doing this?

The key is being pressed because it shows up in xinput and as the correct code.  When I use xev, however, I see a FocusOut event with mode NotifyGrab.  I've checked the obvious places that might set up grabs - the XFCE window managar and the XFCE Keyboard Application Shortcuts and neither of them do anything with this key.

Comment: try https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261371

Comment: That worked, except that the grab was quite a ways back in the log, so adding '-n3000' to the tail was necessary.

Comment: I will then vote to close this as a duplicate of [How do I find out what program 'owns' a hotkey?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261371/how-do-i-find-out-what-program-owns-a-hotkey)

Comment: Sure, go ahead, or do I have to do that?